# Can't instantiate Controller with Castle using webapi as well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, castle

I'm working in a project that uses both ApiControllers and Controllers (not webapi) with Castle (from Nuget)

```
 internal class WebWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IProjUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<ProjUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<Api.CategoriesController>()
                .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<CategoriesController>()
                .BasedOn<IController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
    }
```

This in global.asax (Application_Start)

```
var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
```

And this is the Controller constructor of CategoriesController

```
public class CategoriesController : ControllerBase
{
    public CategoriesController(IProjUow uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
    }
}
```

And ControllerBase inherites from Controller

The ApiController is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
    protected IProjUow Uow { get; set; }
}

public class CategoriesController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public CategoriesController(IProjUow uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
    }
}
```

The ApiController works ok, but the other one says:

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Why?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11484904/246811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Phil's link pointed me in the right direction. I'll share my solution in case anyone is having the same problem.

This should be in Global.asax.cx (Application_Start method)

```
// Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
var webApicontainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver(webApicontainer);

// Set the dependency resolver for Mvc Controllers
Container = new WindsorContainer()
    .Install(new ControllersInstaller());
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MvcWindsorDependencyResolver(Container)); 
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(Container)); 
var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(Container.Kernel); 
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

WebApiWindsorDependecyResolver

```
 internal class WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

        public WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("container"); }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.Kernel.HasComponent(t) ? this.container.Resolve(t) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.ResolveAll(t).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new ReleasingDependencyScope(this as IDependencyScope, this.container.Release);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

MvcWindsorDependencyResolver

```
 internal class MvcWindsorDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

        public MvcWindsorDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>() : new object[] { };
        }
    }
```

ControllerInstaller

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(FindControllers().Configure(c => c.LifestyleTransient()));

            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IProjUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<ProjUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }

        private static BasedOnDescriptor FindControllers()
        {

            return AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
        }
    }
```

WebWindsorInstaller

```
 internal class WebWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IProjUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<ProjUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<Api.CategoriesController>()
                .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
    }
```

The only thing I don't get quite well (despite this works) is Why do I need to have two classes DependencyResolver (WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver and MvcWindsorDependencyResolver) when they are almost the same. Can I get rid of one of them?

If I change the code and instead of

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MvcWindsorDependencyResolver(Container));
```

I write

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver(Container));
```

It says

```
The type Proj.UI.Cms.Infrastructure.WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.
Parameter name: commonServiceLocator
```

But both classes seems to share the same code.

Best Regards. Guillermo.

Comment: Maybe have the one class implement both interfaces?

Comment: Both implements same interface (IWindsorInstaller)

Comment: Sorry, I keep not getting what you meen. Can you please tell me which class should implement IDependencyResolver that doesn't implement it now?
Thanks!! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still experiencing this problem, the solution is to implement right IDependencyResolver interface either from System.Web.Http.Dependencies or from System.Web.Mvc.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21459761 for answer.