# The type does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am new to MVC, i am following "**PRO ASP.NET MVC 4 by Adam Freeman**". I am currently working on its 6th chapter. In which i am learning how to use **Ninject in MVC 4** for Dependency Injection. I have created the application as described in the book. Now i am not getting why the following Error Comes:

> the type NinjectDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator

Here is my Controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Product[] products = {
        new Product {Name = "Kayak", Category = "Watersports", Price = 275M},
        new Product {Name = "Lifejacket", Category = "Watersports", Price = 48.95M},
        new Product {Name = "Soccer ball", Category = "Soccer", Price = 19.50M},
        new Product {Name = "Corner flag", Category = "Soccer", Price = 34.95M}
    };
    private IValueCalculator calc;
    public HomeController(IValueCalculator calcParam)
    {
        calc = calcParam;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(calc) { Products = products };
        decimal totalvalue = cart.CalculateProductTotal();
        return View(totalvalue);
    }
}
```

I have created a class named as "NinjectDependencyResolver" as below:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : DependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernal;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernal = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }


    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernal.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernal.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernal.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();
    }
}
```

Changed the global file as below:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver( new NinjectDependencyResolver());
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

on the "DependencyResolver.SetResolver( new NinjectDependencyResolver());" this line of i am getting the error:

> The type EssentialTools.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver does not appear to implement Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator.
> Parameter name: commonServiceLocator

Please help me, how can i resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use Ninject.MVC3 package which is easier to integrate. It supports MVC 4.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları why? is there any problem with "Ninject Ioc container for .NET"

Comment: Nope, it uses the same Ninject package. It simplifies the integration to an MVC application.

Comment: does the above error due that? @UfukHacıoğulları

Comment: Nope, you are not using that package. You are integrating it manually.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları thanks i made a silly mistake. by the thank you very much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that your `NinjectDependencyResolver` doesn't implement the `IDependencyResolver` interface, but inherits from the `DependencyResolver` class. The `DependencyResolver` does not implement `IDependencyResolver` and this causes your own methods to be unrelated to anything MVC knows.

Just change to:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
```

But as Ufuk Hacıoğulları says, you can use the official Ninject.MVC3 NuGet package to integrate Ninject with MVC. This package is created by the developers of Ninject and depends on the Ninject core library.

Comment: Thanks dude i will.. use NinJect MVC3 too

Comment: I'm using Pro ASP.NET MVC 5, the most current version of the book (published in 2013). It does use the parent class of IDependencyResolver, as shown in Steven's answer. Unfortunately for me, I missed it when entering the code, and ended up on this SO question :-).

Comment: In the class NinjectDependencyResolver also make sure you are referencing System.Web.Mvc, I was using by mistake System.Web.Http.Dependencies as it was the suggestion that I got from Resharper.

Answer (score 18):

One year after, I encountred the same problem... Thanks to pdb's answer, I could find a work-around.
Forcing `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver` instead of `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver` in the customized `NinjectDependencyResolver` caused cast problems in cases other parts of code need the `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`. For example when you try to generalize the customized DI :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)
```

In my case, I implemented the both `IDependencyResolver` and it worked like this :

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver
    : NinjectDependencyScope
    , IDependencyResolver
    , System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
```

Comment: Exact problem I had!  Thank you, this is a great solution and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6):

I made a similar mistake at the same point. I had implemented `IDependencyResolver` and got the identical error. It was caused by the wrong 'using' statement - there is a similar `IDependencyResolver` in `System.Web.Http`. Check you are using `System.Web.Mvc`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by implementing the `IDependencyResolver` interface on the `StructureMapDependencyResolver` class.